# Processing location in the BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, location

I could see an option in BQ UI to specify processing location. What is that? I see it has as option Asia, US and EU. Can I choose where to process my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to specify this processing location option as your dataset location as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations). If you try to run a query to a table stored in Europe and specifying processing location as US, this query will fail.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Location was introduced in [`February 8, 2018`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#february_8_2018) release and specifies geographic location of the job. Required except for US and EU
If your data is in a [`location`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations) other than the US or EU multi-region, you must specify the location when you perform actions such as loading data, querying data, and exporting data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I have to specify for asia locate dataset

Comment: yes. otherwise you will get error - even during validation / dry run

Comment: Yes. I see it gives me an error. Thank you all for the help